# What are numbers which are reverse digits of each other when divided by each other gives finite numbers after decimal point (non periodics)

Tags: number-theory

Are there numbers which are reverse digits of each other when divided by each other gives a finite numbers after decimal point(non periodic)? For example (xyz are digits) xy/yx=abc.abcfinite and yx/xy=abc.abcfinite. For example 81/18=4.5 , 18/81=0.2222... (which is periodic, i dont want this). Ignore those case in which last digits are entirely 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a fraction has a terminating decimal representation, its denominator (in shortest terms) is divisible only by $2$ and $5$, but no other prime. If this holds for both ways to form the quotient, i.e. both $\frac{xy}{yx}$ and $\frac{yx}{xy}$, then both denominator and numerator are of this form. This means that one of the fractions is of the form $\frac{2^a}{5^b}$.

**Simple cases:** $b=0$. Then the quotient is a power of $2$, and must be $<10$ (because both numbers have the same numbr of digits). This leaves the possibilities $\frac{x\cdots y}{y\cdots x}=2^a=1$ (which works for palindromes), $=2$, $=4$, or $=8$.
In the last three cases, $y$ is an even digit.

If $2^a=8$, this means $9\ge x\ge 8y\ge 16$, which is impossible.

If $2^a=4$, we get $9\ge x\ge 4y$, hence $y=2$, then $x=8$ (because $4\cdot 8=(3)2$; a two-digit solution ($\frac{82}{28}$) does not work; the digit after $y$ must be $\le 2$ and odd, so it must be $1$. Then the penultimate digit must be $2$ or $7$, but $2$ is too small. So we are now arrived at $\frac{87\cdots12}{21\cdots78}$. Incidentally, the base case already is a solution: $\frac{8712}{2178}=4, \frac{2178}{8712}=0.25$.

Similar methods can be used to investigate the case $2^a=2$.
The next simple case is $a=0$. Then $b=1$, i.e. $\frac{x\cdots y}{y\cdots x}=5$. Then $y=5$ and hence $9\ge x\ge 5y=25$, contradiction.
The general case $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ seems to be somewhat harder to tackle. At least we find that e.g. $y=5$ and $x$ is an even digit.